# Finding overlapping annotations using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, overlapping-features, annotation

I use about 10 annotations to produce my map. Every single one has been created separately using Tiled Labels to Annotation. I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3

Is there a way to find the annotations that overlap each other?

Comment: if there is only 10 what prevent you to visually check for overlap

Comment: Probably 10 annotation feature classes with lots of labels in each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert each annotation to polygons:

```
arcpy.FeatureOutlineMasks_cartography("AnnoB", ..method="EXACT")
```

Merge them together and intersect with single input. Picture below shows annotations by black and blue, their intersection shown by red:

[image]